# Converting and graphing between polar and Cartesian coordinates

Tags: coordinate-systems, polar-coordinates

I’m asked to convert and then verify by graphing the polar equation: $\theta = \frac{2\pi}{3}$ 
After I converted, I got $y = -x\sqrt{3}$. I can graph $y$, but how do I graph $\theta$?

Comment: There is no graphing of $\theta$. Your polar equation where $\theta$ is given to be a constant, is always a line starting in the Origin. Mind you, that you should only consider the line in the second quadrant, in the fourth quadrant, there is a different $\theta$

Comment: all the points where $\theta=\frac{2\pi}3$ are on that line

Comment: Remember how polar coordinates work: $\theta$ is an angle and $r$ is a radius. If you only specify $\theta$, you’re considering every possible radius on that angle; it’s a whole line going through the origin on that angle. When you made the transformation, you correctly got the equation of this line, in terms of $x$ and $y$. You may draw this line and then indicate that it is $\theta$ radians anti-clockwise around from the $x$-axis.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the graph---very straightforward:

[image]